# Разбить видео на кадры c помощью ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Есть вот такая команда в Linux. Она разбивает видео на кадры.

```
ffmpeg -i imput.mp4 img%03d.jpg
```

Но мне бы хотелось что-бы она разбивала видео скажем не на каждый кадр. А скажем на каждые 10. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте фильтр [select](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr img%03d.jpg
```

Параметр -vsync со значением vfr означает, что кадры с одинаковой временной меткой не пойдут на вывод. Без этого параметра вы получите дублирование выходных кадров, то есть каждый 10 кадр "заместит" последующие 9, и на выходе вы получите то же количество кадров, что и в исходном видео.

Впрочем, лучше один раз увидеть.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!